# How WKWebView runs JS to control window.scrollTo(x,y) when loading document

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

When I use WKWebView, I hope that ONLoad can load JS. In the previous UIwebView, this method is possible. Now I must monitor whether the HTML is loaded and then execute the ONLoad parameter. JS cannot be executed synchronously, which is slower than before. A lot.

I control window.scrollTo(x,y) through JS to realize that when he enters the document reading, it will automatically restore to the last reading progress. In the previous UIwebView, he was triggered synchronously.

At present, I use WKWebView, he must first determine the completion of loading HTML, and then trigger this JS, I tried to execute when HTML is loaded, but this is invalid, WKWebView control loading JS has become very slow, I hope it can I found a solution, I hope someone can help me, I don’t know much about English, so this is the result of Google Translate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject a script that should be executed on load like this:

```
NSString *scriptString = @"window.scrollTo(0,1000);";
WKUserScript *script = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptString injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
[self.webView.configuration.userContentController addUserScript:script];
```

Here you can find the documentation of WKUserScript: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscript?language=objc

If the injection time is still too early you can try to add a WKNavigationDelegate and call your script like below (sorry for the Swift code, maybe someone can edit and convert to objective-c)

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
    if complete != nil {
      self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("window.scrollTo(0,1000);")
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried to inject JS during loading, but I found that it didn’t work. He had to work after loading HTML completely. I guess that JS can only get the width after loading HTML. About window.scrollTo this function

Comment: acording to the documentation the script should be executed after the document is loaded when using injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuserscriptinjectiontime?language=objc

Comment: I added another method to the answer, hope this works for you

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying

Comment: Thank you very much, although he is still slower than UIwebview, but it has been solved. You don’t have to wait until it is fully loaded to execute, I thank you so much.

Comment: Please accept the answer if your problem was solved :)

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time using stackoverflow, thank you very much

Comment: I know. Welcome to SO :)